# Dragon NaturallySpeaking can only send commands to Microsoft Word: dictation doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, dragon-naturally-speaking

From time to time, Dragon NaturallySpeaking can only send commands to a Microsoft Word document, and doesn't allow me to dictate in the Microsoft Word document. What could be the issue?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Microsoft Word 2013 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I did check that Dragon NaturallySpeaking is in normal mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NatSpeak Word Add-in is inactive. This is what allows Dragon to dictate into Word. It's one of the most common errors with Dragon. Why it happens is unclear. Just blame it on Word. Or Dragon. Or both.

Usually this resolves the error. In Word, click on File - Options (or Extras, not sure in English) - Add-ins - Go and check the box next to NatSpeak Word Addin. This should enable it again.

[image]